# Can access all users mailbox's in Outlook Web Access

Tags: security, outlook, outlook-web-app, mailbox

Once i've logged into my work OWA, i've found i can access any other staff members mailbox simply by changing my username to theirs in the web address box!  How do i turn off this scary 'feature'???

And can someone with someone add the 'outlook-web-access' tag please

Cheers

Comment: Will "owa" do..?

Comment: Try doing this on a non-administrator account

Comment: Tried it, still have access to all users mailboxes.

Comment: Sounds like you have permissions issues on your mailboxes. I would start looking there before blaming OWA.

Comment: Managed to fix this - found that 'EVERYONE' group had full control of mailboxes for some unknown reason(!?).  Couldn't change mailbox permissions on individual users properties, had to locate 'Mailbox Store (MY_SERVERNAME)' on Exchange server and change permissions on the Security Tab in it's properties.

Thanks for the suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you an exchange / domain admin by any chance?

Comment: Yes but i've set up another standard user test account and i can do it from this account too.

Comment: Something is wrong with your Exchange security settings then.  My guess is if you take that same test user you can open up anyones inbox via Outlook.

Answer (score 1):

This site may help find the issue.

http://telnetport25.wordpress.com/2007/07/25/default-security-permissions-on-an-exchange-mailbox-2003/

Answer (score 0):

this can happen due to different reasons,

First -> a device that is caching Users credentials can allow person A to gain access to person B's mailbox.

Second -> http://support.microsoft.com/kb/173658"

Under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\InetInfo\Parameters

Add DWORD Value, and add the following: 
Value Name: UserTokenTTL 
Data Type: REG_DWORD 
Data: (Number of seconds for token to be cached - 30 second min)

Regards,
Vivek.